# How to reset Bash on Mac OSX, .bash_profile corrupted and bash no longer works

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, .bash-profile

I am on a MacBook Pro, running the latest version of Mountain Lion.

I really need some help, I have managed some how to damage my .bash_profile (I think) so that every time I open up the terminal I get the error listed below.

```
-bash: export: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/go/bin': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/Users/rob/Applications/sbt/bin:': not a valid identifier
env: bash: No such file or directory
env: bash: No such file or directory
env: bash: No such file or directory
env: bash: No such file or directory
env: bash: No such file or directory
-bash: tar: command not found
-bash: grep: command not found
-bash: cat: command not found
-bash: find: command not found
```

I am not sure what has happened, I have no sudo, cd or any normal commands. The only way I have been able to get to any of the main directories is through the go to folder command in finder and try to find the file to no avail.

To top it all off I think I created a file that might be causing the issue, I wanted to edit the .bash_profile so I typed

```
sudo nano ./bash_profile
```

This open a new file in nano which I think was then saved. After this I opened the real .bash_profile to add in the path for node.js.

If I can get to the .bash_profile I think I can get it back on track but I can't find it, should I reinstall bash? If so how would I do that on a mac, I tried using

```
brew install bash
```

to which I get

```
-bash: brew: command not found
```

Comment: First thing I would try is change to a different shell to be able to sort out the problem: see here on how to do that http://support.apple.com/kb/TA27005. This should enable you to modify / remove the offending file and change the shell back to `bash`.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried reinstalling bash but the only thing that has changed is that `-bash: export: '/Users/rob/Applications/sbt/bin:': not a valid identifier` has gone. The one thing I am struggling with is were the first line might be stored, I have looked in my .bash_profile, .profile and .bashrc but nothing.

Comment: Ok so I added `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/go/bin` to my .bash_profile and it seems to have fixed bash but I still get this error  `-bash: export: '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/go/bin': not a valid identifier` Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try the following: `PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH" # Make sure to use double quotes not single quotes`
And on a new line `export PATH`.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have worked. Please can I just ask why you thought that would work?

Comment: `PATH="<whatever">` sets a shell variable named PATH - in this case it would only be a local variable for the process or script. By invoking `export PATH` you take this variable and export it into the `environment` - this way it will be inherited from processes that are started from the current environment.
It is important to note that you use `export` with the variable name and not `export "some string"` as that would only be a value and no variable. This was the main difference between your original `export` - you can also write `export PATH="<some_value>"`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just putting all my comments together for an answer:

First thing you should do is change the shell, this way you can set a shell that will not load the bash init-scripts (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`) - how to do this for the Mac OS X terminal app can be seen here: [Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA27005)

Now you should be able to open a terminal again and use your favourite command-line editor to open the `.bash_profile` file (e.g. `nano` or `vi`):

In this file you have to reset your `PATH` variable that is used by the terminal to find the programs it can execute.

This can be done with the following two lines:

```
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH" # Make sure to use double quotes not single quotes And on a new line 
export PATH
```

This will first set the directories that you want to have on your PATH and the export this PATH to make it available to all programs started from this shell (via export).

Answer (score 24):

⇧⌘. shows hidden files in file dialogs. You could try opening ~/.bash_profile with TextEdit and making it blank temporarily.

Comment: +1 for the useful keyboard shortcut I didn't know :)

Comment: note: .bash_profile is at you home directory (Users/[username]/.bash_profile

Answer (score 5):

I was running on the same problem, and I just found simpler solution:

`/usr/bin/nano .bash_profile`

delete all your mess, then save the file

Comment: Best answer. Easy and guaranteed to work.

Comment: This answer helped me figure out what to do. In my case, I did this and it didn't let me save it after modifying it, so I had to add `/usr/bin/sudo` in front of it

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread but just wanted to leave here my solution in the hope someone else happens to have the same issue.

When I ran terminal from MacOS it was ok with my own user, but when changed to sudo it couldn't work (command not found).

I ended up fixing it with:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Just removed the path that was causing the error. Restarted the terminal and everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered recently that DOS style files cause problems for both .bash* scripts in OS-X. I have to use DOS file endings for some code shared with Windows users, so if I edit .bash_profile while in that git repo I get lots of error messages when running the script (at login). The utility dos2unix fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the previously mentioned showing of hidden files and using a text editor, there is also an easier way to open a new shell without changing your default shell.  You could alt-click the Terminal app and choose "New Command...".  Then type "sh" into the dialog and run that.  This would open a non-bash shell and you could edit the file there.  In the future it would be a good idea to keep a shell open or test running the new .bash_profile prior to exiting.