# .bash_profile broke my ipython, conda

Tags: macos, mac, bash, terminal

I am using a Mac OSX, updated my bash_profile after following the instructions in one of the Udacity courses. However I am no longer able to access to my ipython notebook or even conda. I get the following

```
conda --version 
-bash: conda: command not found
```

also:

```
ipython nootebook 
-bash: ipythone: command not found
```

I am not sure how to fix this. I tryied erasing my `.bash_profile` file but it does not work. I also tried the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067625/how-to-restore-bash-profile-on-a-mac-none-of-my-unix-terminal-are-working) did not work and [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/498312/how-to-reset-bash-on-mac-osx-bash-profile-corrupted-and-bash-no-longer-works) did not work either. I have also noticed that my the title in my terminal has and extra - . It reads `carlosdelamora-- -bash--80x24` and I believe it used to be `carlosdelamora--bash--80x24`. I do not know if that is relevant.

Comment: I should say that I did not updated my .bash_profile file but I created one. I also have a .bash_profile-anaconda.bak, .bash_profile.pysave in my home directory.

Comment: Assuming default anaconda installation path, you just need to add this line to .bash_profile    `export PATH=$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that you have lost the PATH command added by Anaconda.

Add this to your `.bash_profile`

`export PATH="/Users/<username>/anaconda/bin:$PATH"`

(Replacing `<username>` with your username, of course.)

Comment: It now has conda working. At least when I type conda --version I found it. However it still not working the way it used to be. I have two other files .bash_profile-anaconda.bak
.bash_profile.pysave

Comment: Ok I added .bash_profile-anaconda.bak and it works as it used to.